# Why is Cortana failing to search online?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, tablet, 7.1-nougat

In case it matters: Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0, running Android 6.0.1 (plus whatever Samsung's put on top of it, too). Region is Australia.

Just got the Cortana Assistant app a couple days ago. Mostly just to try it out, but actually really enjoying it all so far. I even have it set as my default assistant app now, so that with one long home-button press, up she pops from any screen, ready to take my request. There is, however, one glaring issue...

If the app can't find what I'm looking for, it looks like it tries to find it online (which is correct behaviour, of course) but... it can't? To wit, I'll just type in something like "linkedin", it'll think about it for about 5 seconds, then this screen will come up saying "No results found for **linkedin**", plus generic terms for making sure I'm searching correctly, e.g. "Ensure words are spelled correctly", "Try rephrasing keywords or using synonyms", etc.

She can say jokes, put in reminders, do all the stuff she needs to do to integrate with other apps on my tablet. But when I ask anything which requires an internet search, she fails onto this screen.

I thought maybe it was some weird thing to do with Bing, so I then did things like install the Bing app, made Bing the default search engine in the Android settings, then restarted the tablet, but that did nothing (I didn't think it would do anything - I thought if Cortana relied on having another app installed then she would've just told me rather than having this generic "no results found" screen - but I thought it was worth a shot).

I also looked extensively online, but I couldn't find any answer to this particular problem.

So... Any help?

---

EDIT: Hmm, it seems like Bing can be reached, or not quite? Now it's getting stranger...

It looks like Bing can be reached, possibly, because if it's something that clearly was meant to be a search, it will occasionally show Bing Ads above the message telling me that nothing could be found for the query. However, the Bing ads are definitely related to the query I entered.

Other times, if it's looking for something, the screen which is obviously meant to show results from a search is just completely white/blank.

Something else is obviously going on here, but I'm still stumped as to what...

Comment: I have the same problem here with my Galaxy Tab A 9.7 and Android 7.1.1

Comment: @clst Well I'm glad I'm not the only one... though if I'm not, then Microsoft is seriously dropping the ball. Because I got so bored of this issue, I just swapped to using all Google stuff, no more Cortana on my tablet. I will also update the question with a new tag though, because I was still getting the issue when my tablet updated to Android 7, which is when I decided to call it quits on Cortana.

Comment: I just checked on my HTC One M8 that is still running Android 4.4. There it works perfectly fine. I used Cortana beta 2.7.1 which claims it is the latest version (but I am pretty sure it isn't). Seems MS dropped proper Android support quite a while ago :(